# develop an application similar to windows explorer

Tags: c#, winapi, pdf

Is it possible to use windows api and c# to develop an application similar to windows explorer [treeview,listview].

```
ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
                if (folder != null && System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string[] arrImageName=new string[1000];
                        int Count = 0;
                        string CutName;
                        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@folder);
                        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string strSplit;
                                strSplit = file.FullName;
                                string[] ClickImg = strSplit.Split('.');
                                string strPDFpath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lenin\\My Documents\\pdf.jpg";

                                if (ClickImg[1] == "pdf") //if (ClickImg[1] == "pptx")
                                {

                                    ShellThumbnail shellThumbnail = new ShellThumbnail();
                                    Bitmap bmp = shellThumbnail.GetThumbnail(@file.FullName);
                                    bmp.Save(@folder +"\\"+ "Test.bmp");

                                    ////imageList.ImageSize = new Size(140, 140);
                                    ////imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                                    ////Image image = (Image)bit;
                                    //////Image img1 = Image.FromFile(strPDFpath);
                                    ////CutName = file.FullName;
                                    ////CutName = CutName.Replace(folder, "");
                                    ////CutName = CutName.Replace("\\", "");
                                    ////arrImageName[Count] = CutName;
                                    ////imageList.Images.Add(FormatImage(imageList.ImageSize.Width, image));
                                    //////imageList.Images.Add(FormatImage(imageList.ImageSize.Width, img1));
                                    ////Count = Count + 1;




                                    //imageList.ImageSize = new Size(140, 140);
                                    //imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                                    //Image img1 = Image.FromFile(strPDFpath);
                                    //CutName = file.FullName;
                                    //CutName = CutName.Replace(folder, "");
                                    //CutName = CutName.Replace("\\", "");
                                    //arrImageName[Count] = CutName;
                                    //imageList.Images.Add(FormatImage(imageList.ImageSize.Width, img1));
                                    //Count = Count + 1;                                       

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    imageList.ImageSize = new Size(140, 140);
                                    imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                                    Image img1 = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);                                       
                                    CutName = file.FullName;
                                    CutName = CutName.Replace(folder, "");
                                    CutName = CutName.Replace("\\", "");
                                    arrImageName[Count] = CutName;
                                    imageList.Images.Add(FormatImage(imageList.ImageSize.Width, img1));
                                    Count = Count + 1;
                                }

                            }
                            catch
                            {
                               Console.WriteLine("This is not an image or pdf file.");

                            }     
                        }


                        for (int j = 0; j < imageList.Images.Count; j++)
                        {
                            this.ListView1.Items.Add((j + 1) + "/" + imageList.Images.Count + " " + "\r\n" + arrImageName[j]);                                
                            this.ListView1.Items[j].ImageIndex = j;
                        }

                        this.ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
                        this.ListView1.LargeImageList = imageList;
                        //import(folder);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
```

Im able to generate thumbnail for "ppt" file using class

```
using System;
```

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TreeListViewDragDrop
{
    public class ShellThumbnail : IDisposable
    {

```
    [Flags]
    private enum ESTRRET
    {
        STRRET_WSTR = 0,
        STRRET_OFFSET = 1,
        STRRET_CSTR = 2
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum ESHCONTF
    {
        SHCONTF_FOLDERS = 32,
        SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = 64,
        SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN = 128,
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum ESHGDN
    {
        SHGDN_NORMAL = 0,
        SHGDN_INFOLDER = 1,
        SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR = 16384,
        SHGDN_FORPARSING = 32768
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum ESFGAO
    {
        SFGAO_CANCOPY = 1,
        SFGAO_CANMOVE = 2,
        SFGAO_CANLINK = 4,
        SFGAO_CANRENAME = 16,
        SFGAO_CANDELETE = 32,
        SFGAO_HASPROPSHEET = 64,
        SFGAO_DROPTARGET = 256,
        SFGAO_CAPABILITYMASK = 375,
        SFGAO_LINK = 65536,
        SFGAO_SHARE = 131072,
        SFGAO_READONLY = 262144,
        SFGAO_GHOSTED = 524288,
        SFGAO_DISPLAYATTRMASK = 983040,
        SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR = 268435456,
        SFGAO_FOLDER = 536870912,
        SFGAO_FILESYSTEM = 1073741824,
        SFGAO_HASSUBFOLDER = -2147483648,
        SFGAO_CONTENTSMASK = -2147483648,
        SFGAO_VALIDATE = 16777216,
        SFGAO_REMOVABLE = 33554432,
        SFGAO_COMPRESSED = 67108864,
    }

    private enum EIEIFLAG
    {
        IEIFLAG_ASYNC = 1,
        IEIFLAG_CACHE = 2,
        IEIFLAG_ASPECT = 4,
        IEIFLAG_OFFLINE = 8,
        IEIFLAG_GLEAM = 16,
        IEIFLAG_SCREEN = 32,
        IEIFLAG_ORIGSIZE = 64,
        IEIFLAG_NOSTAMP = 128,
        IEIFLAG_NOBORDER = 256,
        IEIFLAG_QUALITY = 512
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, Size = 0, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct STRRET_CSTR
    {
        public ESTRRET uType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 520)]
        public byte[] cStr;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct STRRET_ANY
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ESTRRET uType;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public IntPtr pOLEString;
    }
    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SIZE
    {
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
    }

    [ComImport(), Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IUnknown
    {

        [PreserveSig()]
        IntPtr QueryInterface(ref Guid riid, ref IntPtr pVoid);

        [PreserveSig()]
        IntPtr AddRef();

        [PreserveSig()]
        IntPtr Release();
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("00000002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IMalloc
    {

        [PreserveSig()]
        IntPtr Alloc(int cb);

        [PreserveSig()]
        IntPtr Realloc(IntPtr pv, int cb);

        [PreserveSig()]
        void Free(IntPtr pv);

        [PreserveSig()]
        int GetSize(IntPtr pv);

        [PreserveSig()]
        int DidAlloc(IntPtr pv);

        [PreserveSig()]
        void HeapMinimize();
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("000214F2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IEnumIDList
    {

        [PreserveSig()]
        int Next(int celt, ref IntPtr rgelt, ref int pceltFetched);

        void Skip(int celt);

        void Reset();

        void Clone(ref IEnumIDList ppenum);
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("000214E6-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IShellFolder
    {

        void ParseDisplayName(IntPtr hwndOwner, IntPtr pbcReserved,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpszDisplayName,
          ref int pchEaten, ref IntPtr ppidl, ref int pdwAttributes);

        void EnumObjects(IntPtr hwndOwner,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]ESHCONTF grfFlags,
          ref IEnumIDList ppenumIDList);

        void BindToObject(IntPtr pidl, IntPtr pbcReserved, ref Guid riid,
          ref IShellFolder ppvOut);

        void BindToStorage(IntPtr pidl, IntPtr pbcReserved, ref Guid riid, IntPtr ppvObj);

        [PreserveSig()]
        int CompareIDs(IntPtr lParam, IntPtr pidl1, IntPtr pidl2);

        void CreateViewObject(IntPtr hwndOwner, ref Guid riid,
          IntPtr ppvOut);

        void GetAttributesOf(int cidl, IntPtr apidl,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]ref ESFGAO rgfInOut);

        void GetUIObjectOf(IntPtr hwndOwner, int cidl, ref IntPtr apidl, ref Guid riid, ref int prgfInOut, ref IUnknown ppvOut);

        void GetDisplayNameOf(IntPtr pidl,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]ESHGDN uFlags,
          ref STRRET_CSTR lpName);

        void SetNameOf(IntPtr hwndOwner, IntPtr pidl,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpszName,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ESHCONTF uFlags,
          ref IntPtr ppidlOut);
    }
    [ComImportAttribute(), GuidAttribute("BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1"), InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IExtractImage
    {
        void GetLocation([Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    StringBuilder pszPathBuffer, int cch, ref int pdwPriority, ref SIZE prgSize, int dwRecClrDepth, ref int pdwFlags);

        void Extract(ref IntPtr phBmpThumbnail);
    }

    private class UnmanagedMethods
    {

        [DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal extern static int SHGetMalloc(ref IMalloc ppMalloc);

        [DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal extern static int SHGetDesktopFolder(ref IShellFolder ppshf);

        [DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal extern static int SHGetPathFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, StringBuilder pszPath);

        [DllImport("gdi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal extern static int DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    }

    ~ShellThumbnail()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    private IMalloc alloc = null;
    private bool disposed = false;
    private Size _desiredSize = new Size(100, 100);
    private Bitmap _thumbNail;

    public Bitmap ThumbNail
    {
        get
        {
            return _thumbNail;
        }
    }

    public Size DesiredSize
    {
        get { return _desiredSize; }
        set { _desiredSize = value; }
    }
    private IMalloc Allocator
    {
        get
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (alloc == null)
                {
                    UnmanagedMethods.SHGetMalloc(ref alloc);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Assert(false, "Object has been disposed.");
            }
            return alloc;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap GetThumbnail(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            return null;

        if (!File.Exists(fileName) && !Directory.Exists(fileName))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("The file '{0}' does not exist", fileName), fileName);
        }
        if (_thumbNail != null)
        {
            _thumbNail.Dispose();
            _thumbNail = null;
        }
        IShellFolder folder = null;
        try
        {
            folder = getDesktopFolder;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        if (folder != null)
        {
            IntPtr pidlMain = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                int cParsed = 0;
                int pdwAttrib = 0;
                string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
                folder.ParseDisplayName(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, filePath, ref cParsed, ref pidlMain, ref pdwAttrib);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
                throw ex;
            }
            if (pidlMain != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Guid iidShellFolder = new Guid("000214E6-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
                IShellFolder item = null;
                try
                {
                    folder.BindToObject(pidlMain, IntPtr.Zero, ref iidShellFolder, ref item);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
                    Allocator.Free(pidlMain);
                    throw ex;
                }
                if (item != null)
                {
                    IEnumIDList idEnum = null;
                    try
                    {
                        item.EnumObjects(IntPtr.Zero, (ESHCONTF.SHCONTF_FOLDERS | ESHCONTF.SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS), ref idEnum);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
                        Allocator.Free(pidlMain);
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    if (idEnum != null)
                    {
                        int hRes = 0;
                        IntPtr pidl = IntPtr.Zero;
                        int fetched = 0;
                        bool complete = false;
                        while (!complete)
                        {
                            hRes = idEnum.Next(1, ref pidl, ref fetched);
                            if (hRes != 0)
                            {
                                pidl = IntPtr.Zero;
                                complete = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (_getThumbNail(fileName, pidl, item))
                                {
                                    complete = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (pidl != IntPtr.Zero)
                            {
                                Allocator.Free(pidl);
                            }
                        }
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(idEnum);
                    }
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
                }
                Allocator.Free(pidlMain);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
        }
        return ThumbNail;
    }

    private bool _getThumbNail(string file, IntPtr pidl, IShellFolder item)
    {
        IntPtr hBmp = IntPtr.Zero;
        IExtractImage extractImage = null;
        try
        {
            string pidlPath = PathFromPidl(pidl);
            if (Path.GetFileName(pidlPath).ToUpper().Equals(Path.GetFileName(file).ToUpper()))
            {
                IUnknown iunk = null;
                int prgf = 0;
                Guid iidExtractImage = new Guid("BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1");
                item.GetUIObjectOf(IntPtr.Zero, 1, ref pidl, ref iidExtractImage, ref prgf, ref iunk);
                extractImage = (IExtractImage)iunk;
                if (extractImage != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Got an IExtractImage object!");
                    SIZE sz = new SIZE();
                    sz.cx = DesiredSize.Width;
                    sz.cy = DesiredSize.Height;
                    StringBuilder location = new StringBuilder(260, 260);
                    int priority = 0;
                    int requestedColourDepth = 32;
                    EIEIFLAG flags = EIEIFLAG.IEIFLAG_ASPECT | EIEIFLAG.IEIFLAG_SCREEN;
                    int uFlags = (int)flags;
                    try
                    {
                        extractImage.GetLocation(location, location.Capacity, ref priority, ref sz, requestedColourDepth, ref uFlags);
                        extractImage.Extract(ref hBmp);
                    }
                    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
                    {

                    }
                    if (hBmp != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        _thumbNail = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBmp);
                    }
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(extractImage);
                    extractImage = null;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (hBmp != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                UnmanagedMethods.DeleteObject(hBmp);
            }
            if (extractImage != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(extractImage);
            }
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private string PathFromPidl(IntPtr pidl)
    {
        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(260, 260);
        int result = UnmanagedMethods.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return path.ToString();
        }
    }

    private IShellFolder getDesktopFolder
    {
        get
        {
            IShellFolder ppshf = null;
            int r = UnmanagedMethods.SHGetDesktopFolder(ref ppshf);
            return ppshf;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (alloc != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(alloc);
            }
            alloc = null;
            if (_thumbNail != null)
            {
                _thumbNail.Dispose();
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Similar how -- are you asking about a generic split treeview/listview application backing onto some data specific to your app, or about building a custom app that traverses the Windows filesystem / shell namespace?

Comment: Err... sure. Why don't you have a go at whatever it is you're trying to do, and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: thank itowlson,im trying to build the same application.

Comment: What exactly is your question...?

Comment: peSHir thank you for the interest,How to generate thumbnail image from pdf document?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the API here. Have a look at the Controls and at the Directory, File and Path-Classes within the System.IO-Namespace. Everything you'd need is in this three classes.

F.e.:

```
foreach(String filename in Directory.GetFiles(yourPath))
```

Bobby

Comment: thank you Bobby,im struck up at point where i have to generate thumbnail for pdf.

Comment: Generating thumbnails for PDFs isn't easy. You'll need a renderer doing this...but I'm afraid that there nearly no components for this for the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the VCL has nessary compants and you can do command just list you do in cmd to get the data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the .NET Directory classes hook in to higher performance operating system services (WinAPI) to retrieve files.

For example I wrote a simple app. to list files and folders in a given directory in .NET.  When I pointed this to say C:\Windows\System32 (containing about 2300 files), my application takes >5 seconds to retrieve all files, where-as windows explorer does this in less then a second.

This may not be an issue for you, but it is surprising.  If anyone knows why or how to improve this performance I'm interested to hear.